# Best way to stream FFMpeg AVFrame objects from a C++ application to Python?

Tags: python, c++, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I have a C++ application which generates a stream of AVFrame objects and I want to pass them in realtime to a Python application for further processing, e.g. using OpenCV.

What is the best way of doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a Unix or Linux based system, you can use a pipe. You also can use the local socket to transmit the stream.